# I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined" when trying to import chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, extend

The error text: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
(anonymous function)
./node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js:587"

[print of the error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJuQ6.png)

That's the component where i'm trying to import the package.

```
import { Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

const FieldsData = (props) => {
  const getFirstChart = () => {
    const labels = props.fails
      ? props.fails.failsByOcurrence.map((fail) => {
          return fail.label;
        })
      : [];
    const colors = ["#e8e15f", "#e8e15f", "#e64f3e", "#e64f3e", "#e64f3e"];
    const data = {
      labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Intensidade de falhas por intervalo de comprimento",
          barPercentage: 0.6,
          data: props.fails
            ? props.fails.failsByLengthClass.map((x) => {
                return x.value;
              })
            : [],
          backgroundColor: colors,
        },
      ],
    };
    const chartConfig = {
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        plugins: {},
      },
    };
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "90%", margin: "0 auto" }}>
        <Bar data={data} options={chartConfig} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Divider style={{ margin: "0.5rem 0" }} />
      {getFirstChart()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FieldsData;
```

I've tried to use a chart.js that's < 3.0.0. Tried using the chart.js package instead of react-chartjs-2, but i'm always getting this error.

Comment: Please add codesandbox or something else, with the context and a part of your code to help you.

Comment: I've edited the question now. Sorry for the lack of code and details.

Comment: Please post the error as text. Pictures of code/errors are less than useless since they're non searchable and add frustration to users with limited sight.

Comment: I've added the error text. Thanks for the tips, that's the second time I'm asking something here. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution**

you need to register the chartDataLabel

```
import { Bar, Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
```

```
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels); // REGISTER PLUGIN
```

```
  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'label',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        datalabels: {
          color: '#FFCE56',
          anchor: 'end',
          align  : 'start',
          color: function(context) {
            return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
          },
          font: function(context) {
            var w = context.chart.width;
            return {
              size: w < 512 ? 12 : 14,
              weight: 'bold',
            };
          }
        }
      },
    ],
  };
```

```
return (
<Bar data={data}/>
)
```

This post help me to find the solution

[chartjs-plugin-zoom not working with my React project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913985/chartjs-plugin-zoom-not-working-with-my-react-project)

Answer (score 1):

The same phenomenon happened to me.

I think this discussion will be helpful.
[https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/discussions/213#:~:text=chart.js%203%20compatibility](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/discussions/213#:%7E:text=chart.js%203%20compatibility)

The problem is probably a dependency between Chart.js version 3 and chartjs-plugin-datalabels master branch version.

I used this command to solve the problem

```
npm install -S chartjs-plugin-datalabels@next
```

This is how my dependency works.

```
"chart.js": "^3.3.2",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3",
```

I hope this is helpful.