# chartjs-plugin-zoom not working with my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have a react component using the 'react-chartjs-2' library to show some data.
The chart with the data works fine. What I cannot do is make the chart work with the 'chartjs-plugin-zoom' plugin. I am not sure what is wrong with the config.
I am using:

"react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3"

"chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^1.0.1"

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import * as zoom from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom'

import classes from './Chart.module.css'

interface Chart {
  title: string
  labels: string[]
  datasets: any
}

const Chart: React.FC<Chart> = props => {
  const data = {
    title: props.title,
    labels: props.labels,
    datasets: props.datasets,
  }

  const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
      },
      line: {
        borderWidth: 1.5,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'rgba( 0, 0, 1)',
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        },
      },
      y: {
        min: 1,
        max: 200000,
        type: 'logarithmic',
        ticks: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy',
          speed: 100,
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy',
          speed: 100,
        },
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.chartContainer}>
      <Line
        type='line'
        title={props.title}
        data={data}
        options={options}
        width={900}
        height={450}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chart
```

This is the css file, just in case.

```
.chart-container {
  height: 450px;
  width: 900px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2 things, you will have to register the zoomplugin as stated in the documentation by registering it either globally or inline (https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/guide/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc), also your config was incorrect, the zoom option does not have an `enabled` option, you will have to enable all the different zoom types appart, then it will work (https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/guide/options.html#zoom-options)

```js
import { Line, Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";
import React from "react";
import zoomPlugin from "chartjs-plugin-zoom";

Chart.register(zoomPlugin); // REGISTER PLUGIN

const Chart2 = (props) => {
  const data = {
    title: props.title,
    labels: props.labels,
    datasets: props.datasets
  };

  const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      },
      line: {
        borderWidth: 1.5
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: "rgba( 0, 0, 1)"
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        }
      },
      y: {
        min: 1,
        max: 200000,
        type: "logarithmic",
        ticks: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        },
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          wheel: {
            enabled: true // SET SCROOL ZOOM TO TRUE
          },
          mode: "xy",
          speed: 100
        },
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: "xy",
          speed: 100
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Line
        type="line"
        data={data}
        options={options}
        width={900}
        height={450}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart2;
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chart-js-forked-cn6wh?file=/src/components/Chart.js

Comment: Thanks, this was something that I was missing. After that I had a second problem. My NextJS app was referencing a window object which did not exist (due to how server side rendering works). 

I fixed it with this post 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848309/16181400

Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering why pan doesn't work on the x axis if pan is set to "xy"